# How do I remove Tomboy without removing Gnome?

Tags: gnome, package-management, 11.04, tomboy

I would like to remove Tomboy application, but when I run

```
apt-get remove tomboy
```

I get information that also `gnome` application will be removed. How can this be prevented?

Or maybe this could be achieved: how I can remove `tomboy` and keep all other packages that come with `gnome`?

Comment: Strange, on Maverick `gnome` is not installed by default, because `ubuntu-desktop` does not depend on it. Also, `gnome` does not depend on `tomboy`. So, what release of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: I have just upgraded to natty. I have experienced a freeze during upgrade and the installed both `xorg` and `gnome` packages, because otherwise I had no graphical interface.

Comment: You should install `ubuntu-desktop`, instead.

Comment: Your system doesn't work because Natty's in the middle of an X transition: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any package named `gnome`. I think you meant `ubuntu-desktop`

Either your system does not have proper packages list. Do a
`sudo apt-get update`
to check if everything is in order

If the problem still comes, check what all are contained in the package. Chances are high that it is a `metapackage`. It means that a package which has multiple packages as it's dependencies. 
Meta-packages don't contain anything. If you want to install say kubuntu on already existing ubuntu installation then all you need to do is to install `kubuntu-desktop` which will take care of the packages which need to be installed.

Now if you remove any single of the package which are dependency of that meta-package, then that meta-package is shown to be removed.

Don't worry, your whole gnome is not going to be removed. Only the meta-package is going to be unchecked as the dependency requirement for that package is not fulfilled.

I am not very much sure what the problem you are getting. Probably the solution I explained might not be the solution to your problem, nevertheless I thought it is good to explain what all problems can exist with the same symptoms.

Comment: Yes, only the `metapackage` is removed, but then I get information, that ceratin packages from `gnome` are not necessary any more and will be removed, if I run `autoremove`. How can I prevent that?

Comment: Can you please post the complete output in pastebin and post it here so that everyone can have a look

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove Tomboy, APT also want to remove ubuntu-desktop. 
It's safe to remove, because ubuntu-desktop is just a meta-package.

Answer (score -1):

You were very close initially to removing tomboy notes.
simply add `sudo` before your command and that should work. 
I tested on my system and no more tomboy notes.

```
sudo apt-get remove tomboy
```